# Struct and template

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
   T value;
   ListItem<T> *next;
   ListItem<T> *prev;

   ListItem(T theVal)
   {
    this->value = theVal;
    this->next = NULL;
    this->prev = NULL;
   }
};
```

Can somebody please tell me what is happening after the prev pointer has  been declared.I mean what kind of structure is it?Sorry for asking what is probably a silly question.Thanks

Comment: I know what "this" does but why is the value being equated to theVal??

Comment: It's not being "equated", it's being assigned. The member variable `value` gets assigned the value from `theVal`. If you don't know that, you should probably take a step back, and go back to (re)learn the basics.

Comment: so if I want to change the value of a struct say List,i'll have to do List->theVal??

Comment: No, not `theVal`, but `value`

Comment: No, the member is named `value`, the argument to the constructor is `theVal`. After the constructor returns there is nothing in the class named `theVal`. Like I said in my previous comment, take a step back and start over with the basics of C++, like learning what assignment is, what functions are and what an argument is.

Comment: Thanks!I always have these kind of issues

Comment: Try reading a book or following some tutorials on c/c++, these are really basic issues

Answer (score 1):

```
ListItem(T theVal)
{
  this->value = theVal;
  this->next = NULL;
  this->prev = NULL;
}
```

is an inline constructor definition. It specifies how instances of your `ListItem` class template are initialized. the `value` data member is set to `theVal` and the list's `next` and `prev` pointers are set to `NULL`. You would call such a constructor as

```
ListItem<int> li(42);
```

Comment: I prefer the original initialization syntax. It is equivalent in terms of performance and avoids the risk of incurring in [C++'s most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: ...but the "new" had escaped me. Too much Java, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListItem(T theVal)
{
    this->value = theVal;
    this->next = NULL;
    this->prev = NULL;
}
```

This is a constructor for this struct, with `this->value = theVal;` the value that is passed in as an argument is assigned to the struct's member `value`.

If you don't know about constructors yet it would be wise to read up on them.